# What does it mean when Mockito's "when" has multiple 'thenReturn' calls?

Tags: mockito

Here is a code snippet extracted from a mockito unit test I'm working on:

```
        Mockito.when(clientResource.getJobStatus(JOB_ID))
            .thenReturn(createJobStatus(JOB_ID, com.test.models.JobStatus.State.IDLE))
            .thenReturn(createJobStatus(JOB_ID, com.test.models.JobStatus.State.STARTING))
            .thenReturn(createJobStatus(JOB_ID, com.test.models.JobStatus.State.RUNNING));
```

What does it mean when a `Mockito.when(...)` has multiple `thenReturn(...)`'s chained after it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that it will return those values or `answers` in the order they were declared.

The first call to `getJobStatus()` will return `createJobStatus(JOB_ID, com.test.models.JobStatus.State.IDLE)`

The second call will return `createJobStatus(JOB_ID, com.test.models.JobStatus.State.STARTING)`

And so on...

You can see that in [this method](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/release/2.x/src/main/java/org/mockito/internal/stubbing/StubbedInvocationMatcher.java#L29) the `answers` are being polled from a `queue`.

Comment: Right so when the same mock method gets called multiple times these answers will be the ones it hits in order. got it thanks.